# SQL script to change all the cubes to process partially

Tags: ssas

I have a requirement to "write a script to change all the cubes to process partially". This script needs to be something that can be scheduled using a SQL agent job.

I'm happy with SQL Agent but I don't know much about SSAS so I'm struggling a bit. If when using SSMS to process a cube you select the "Script" option you get something like the following:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>MyCube</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

Does this look like it will satisfy the requirement? If so how do I alter it to only process Partially?

Comment: Following the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-scripting-language-assl-xmla/processing-objects-xmla) i would say use `ProcessAdd` instead of `ProcessFull` for partially.

Comment: Also, you can create a SSIS package or project that can process cubes if you're more familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen an article that suggests using SSIS to process the Dimensions and then process the cube but was unsure if this is what is meant by "partially process cubes". I'm comfortable with this approach but it doesn't meet the requirement to provide a script.

Comment: Following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/schedule-ssas-administrative-tasks-with-sql-server-agent) your scripts seems about right, just change the type.